# MRI duplicates memory allocation when Thread.new

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mri

It seems that MRI makes duplication of memory allocation for every new thread.

I use Ubuntu x64, ruby-2.2.4 (rvm), and this what i get:

Just started irb:

[image]

I see `pmap -d 1656` 59760K (*allocated memory, or '[ stack ]' for the program stack [man pmap(1)]*) memory usage:

[image]

And when creating a thread:

[image]

I see `pmap -d 1656` 127352K memory usage:

[image]

So, I see duplication 59760K -> 127352K of memory allocation.

---

Such behavior is similar to result of the `fork()` call, which being used for creation a new process, makes a copy of its calling process data ('copy-on-write' is out this context) for new process.

But Thread is created in the same process and shares its data, and it looks strange...

In practice, it means that Thread in Ruby has similar to Process restriction in memory usage: new thread creation fails when allocated memory getting closer to physical memory size.

I am curious, WHY?

**UPDATE**

It's not duplication memory but additional allocation for ~50K for each thread.
Thanks @tadman for suggestion that it's an overhead and not something like copying memory in the fork()'s way.

Comment: Each thread must allocate enough memory for the stack, and the stack size is defined by [various parameters](http://clearcove.ca/2013/10/how-to-increase-max-stack-size-for-ruby-2-0-when-experiencing-systemstackerror-stack-level-too-deep/), but even then this doesn't account for all of the memory usage seen here. I've reproduced this to a degree on a Fedora machine, but I can run ~500 threads without any problems.

Comment: @tadman, yes, I know that restriction in threads count may looks not really significant, but my questions came from a real case, where I used threads within not-so-small Rails project and I got the limit of memory. But the question is why thread must allocate more memory if it has its memory space already? It uses the shared objects and from this point I see that it's just a routine, that is executing concurrently. Even if it creates variables - its like other variables in other blocks, isn't?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the MRI internals, but I know it has a lot of baggage with respect to the Global Interpreter Lock and various historical compatibility concerns. The new thread does need its own copy of some things, but the things it needs varies considerably from version 1.9 to 2.4 as improvements have been made. The *heap* is shared, but other elements aren't, especially the stack.

Comment: It seems your suggestion has matter. I've tried to allocate some memory with `arr = 10000000.times.inject([]){|a,i| a<<i}` (mapped ~ 300M) and after i made `Thread.new{sleep}` it has added only ~50M to mapped. This amount is very similar to overhead for new thread without additional objects. So, it really may be some overhead for GIL...

Comment: If you can come up with more concrete metrics on what's allocated and if this is actually erroneous, I'm sure the Ruby performance team might be interested. I'm not sure how gnarly the threading C code in MRI is, but that's one place to start digging.

Comment: Well, I am not sure that it's a bug, I guess it's just some conscious overhead of ruby interpreter. But another interesting thing.. I've tried this on Rubinius, where no GIL as I know, and rbx has added some allocation and created new process when Thread.new, with new pid and the same memory mapping size, but object variables still shared.
Well.. It looks like some trick around concurrency-safe of interpreters

Comment: Jruby, Rubinius, and MRI Ruby probably have wildly different memory consumption profiles. I'd expect Rubinius to be the leanest since that's a from-scratch implementation with an emphasis on efficiency, so maybe that's an option if you're getting pinned on memory.

Comment: @tadman, thanks! I will try to dig deeper. Anyway, as for mentioned case with Rails, I think it's not a good idea to process many threaded routines in Rails app - it's better to make another, not bound to Rails process, if possible. It was just curious interest, and knowing)